# PHP localtime() incorrect when executed by Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, time, localtime

I'm trying to write a php script which uses gets the current local time using

```
localtime(time(), true);
```

It's important that this time is set as the same as the local time on the server, which is Europe/London, as there is a crontab which is calling this script once an hour. Also it is important that it takes into account Daylight Savings Time.

The clock on my server is correct, and when I run the function on the PHP interactive shell, the correct time is returned, however when Apache runs the script, it reports *an hour behind*, and *tm_isdst* logs *falsey*.

I have checked my Apache php.ini file, I am sure it is the correct file, as I have checked phpinfo(), however maybe there are other files over-riding this?

I have also tried reloading and restarting Apache (successfully), however it still doesn't take into account the correct time.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding     date.timezone = "Europe/London"         in your php.ini file. Then restart apache2 service. If it works, i'll change my comment for an answer

Comment: Here's a detailed site to sync PHP/MySQL with server time zone : http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/

Comment: @SamyQc Thanks, sorry I maybe wasn't clear about this. My php.ini file has "Europe/London" set. 'date.timezone = "Europe/London"'. Also I have checked using phpinfo() that I am editing the correct .ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quite few options to go with but the most common ones are these two:

**1. List your variables to check**

Check if in your php.ini a timezone is set by using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Then add that function in an empty file, filename i.e. *phpInfo.php* and request that file through your web environment.

You must search for this variable `date.timezone=`. Then try adding it in your local php.ini file. More info on [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php). If you dont have access to the php.ini file go to step 2.

**2. Add timezone into your php file directly**

If you're using any type of MVC or application that uses any kind of bootstrapping files together then your best option is not add `date_default_timezone_set();` into your first php file that you are calling. [Timezones Supported in EU](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)

For a simple test to see if timezone changes or not

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked, and it is added as 'Europe/London'. But it still logs out one hour behind and has tm_isdst as 0

Comment: The default timezone is still set as UTC though, so I guess that has something to do with it, but how could I change this (ideally just for this script rather than the whole server)

Comment: Awesome, I tried the date_default_timezone_set approach and it worked. Thanks so much, :D